# What is the '@' for in 'npm install -g @vue/cli'

Tags: npm, installation

I am curious, what is the '@' for in 'npm install -g @vue/cli'

Why don't they just have it as 'vue/cli' instead of '@vue/cli'?

Comment: same thing w/ angular ...

Answer (score 2):

This is done to resolve the package better. For example, with Webpack [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) configuration option (isn't specific to Vue).

[In Vue Webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), Webpack is configured to replace `@/` with [`src` path](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/9992f5a058c53f32b03d9a8743612188c04698af/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L27):

```
  const path = require('path');

  ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      ...
      '@': path.resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  ...
```

The alias could then be used as:

```
import '@/<path inside src folder>';
```